# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'car' in undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to define sum object which keeps track of count of each string passed to "data" variable. The error says total is undefined. Is it not enough to declare second parameter as {} in reduce function to have total defined.

```js
const data = [
  'car',
  'car',
  'truck',
  'truck',
  'bike',
  'walk',
  'car',
  'van',
  'bike',
  'walk',
  'car',
  'van',
  'car',
  'truck'
];
const sum = data.reduce((total, key) => {
  if (key in total) total[key]++;
  else total[key] = 1;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value in `reduce()` callback which will be used as accumulator(`total` in this case) in the next iteration.

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck' ];
const sum = data.reduce((total,key) => {
  if(key in total) 
    total[key]++; 
  else 
    total[key] = 1; 
  return total;
  },
{});

console.log(sum)
```

You can also do this in one line

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck' ];
const sum = data.reduce((total, key) => ({...total, [key]: (total[key] || 0) + 1}), {});
console.log(sum)
```